# Rigidbodies flying around

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to make an animation of falling dominos and for that, I first created a cube, then used an *Array Modifier* and *Curve Modifier* to turn the cube into a lot of Dominos.

Then, I added *Active* rigid bodies to all the dominoes and *Passive* to the ground plane. Note that there are no intersecting geometries, still, the dominoes start flying all around when the simulation is played.

What is going wrong here?

My Blend file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all and set origin to geometry. Also, select one domino, in the *Rigid Body* panel switch it from *Shape > Mesh* to *Convex Hull*, select all the dominos, select the one you've changed at last, then go into *Object > Rigid Body > Copy From Active*, and it should work. I'm not sure why *Convex Hull* works better.

[image]

Comment: The *Select all and set origin to geometry* seemed to do the trick! Thank you!